# New page for every group in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport 5.6.0 and i want to create new page for each group.

For example i have table `people_i_know`:

```
Id| Name | State
1 | Tom  | friends
2 | Jim  | friends
3 | Mike | enemy
4 | Alex | friends
5 | Julie| enemy
```

My SQL should be like this:

```
SELECT Id,Name,State FROM people_i_know GROUP BY State;
```

And in this example iReport should give me two pages with detail band like this:

This should be on page 1.

```
1 | Tom  | friends
2 | Jim  | friends
4 | Alex | friends
```

And this should be on page 2.

```
3 | Mike | enemy
5 | Julie| enemy
```

How do i make that iReport make something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to group in query, just order them

```xml
SELECT Id,Name,State FROM people_i_know State ORDER BY State;
```

**in jrxml**

you will have a field relative to the `State` column

```xml
<field name="State" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

**create a group** on `State` with attribute `isStartNewPage="true"`

```xml
<group name="State" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{State}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

and now just put the fields you like to display in the `detail` band